# Firefox SSO login on active directory enabled squid

Tags: firefox, single-sign-on, kerberos, samba, squid

I have Linux Domain Controller, it using samba4 to serve DNS and LDAP to the network, and overall works fine. 
I also want it to be a proxy server, so I've installed squid on it. 
I've decided to integrate AD authentication on my proxy server. 
So far I've been able to login on proxy server from Windows Firefox client seamlessly, using squid_ntlm_auth, so it's working. I have DOMAIN\USERNAME in access.log when browsing from this client.
Now I want my Ubuntu client to login on proxy without entering username and password. 
It doesn't work though, it asks me for a password. If I enter my AD username and password, I'm able to browse pages using those credentials until I close Firefox. 
Ubuntu client is connected to AD, I've used Likewise-Open to do it.

Sorry for my poor English.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Drop that NTLM crap right now. It is discouraged. Use SPNEGO with Kerberos (`mod_auth_kerb`) and it'll work.